# Table Array in an HLOOKUP does not have COL letters (e.g. 'Pivot Daily'!$5:$12) I need to understand it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out an old HLOOKUP in one of working files in my new job and the TABLE ARRAY argument does not have COL letters but just letters like `$5:$12`.

I tried googling it but I cannot find the answer, I need help in understanding it so I can modify it the right way.

Here's the complete code:

`=HLOOKUP(E$4,'Pivot Daily'!$5:$12,Dashboard!$C5,FALSE)`

Thank you.

Comment: That just means rows 5 to 12 - the entire row, so no column letters needed.

Comment: Thank BigBen! It was the first time I encountered that reference. Is there a term for it? I mean the "no column letters and only row numbers" referencing?

Comment: I have not heard of a term for it. Note that a reference to an entire column would be `A:A`, no numbers, so this is not something special or unusual.